# What is the meaning of 'Repayment Credit' in banking

Tags: india, banking, bank-statements, fixed-deposits

I had a FD in an Indian Bank. I told the bank to close my FD. While previously, whenever I closed my FD, my bank statement showed the transaction remark as `Closure Proceeds` but on this transaction, it shows remark `Repayment credit`. I inquired with the bank about this issue but they insist that the issue is not serious, that the remark is system generated.

My knowledge is that the remark `Repayment credit` is used only when a loan is created. I am quite concerned about this. Can anyone please explain me what `Repayment credit` is, as I think something fishy is going on.

Comment: Did you get your money?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I did get the money

Comment: Did they credit your bank account with the money from them repaying your CFD?

Comment: @MD-Tech I do not understand the question. What is CFD? Can you please frame the question in a simple way.

Comment: @ZNAXNOR CFD is a typo - I meant FD. As in: Did they credit your bank account with the money from repaying your FD?

Comment: @MD-Tech yes, the bank did credit the money back into my account after closing my FD

Comment: @ZNAXNOR so you're asking why the repayment credit that the bank gave you is labelled as "Repayment Credit"? Sometimes words just mean what they say, can you explain your question in other words?

Comment: @MD-Tech The process of closing an FD is always remarked as `Closure Proceeds` in bank statements. Why is the bank using the term `Repayment Credit` for only this particular transaction? My knowledge is that the term `Repayment Credit` is used only when a loan is created, which was *not* what I asked the bank to do. I fear that the deposited money in my account is not money from *closing* my FD, but rather a loan created on my FD.